# How does one test logic that performs a webrequest in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, unit-testing

I'm in the process of writing a C# equivalent of a Java web service client. Like the Java logic, the C# logic interacts with a web service.

In the Java world, I would test this by using something like jersey to host servlets that mocked the API and recorded interactions with the API client. Is testing in C# a similar process? If so, what how do I do this?

Comment: Are you using WebAPI in C#? You could just add a Unit Test project to the WebAPI and you can add Asserts and whatnot for the data that comes into the WebAPI controller. Am I understanding what you're looking for?

Comment: No. I'm just making straight HttpWebRequest requests to a Java web service. I want to mock this service in my unit tests. Though I think I may have found a solution with the HttpListener.